# How to do distributed updates in HBase without MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

**Problem**

I have some jobs that just need to iterate over every record in an HBase table and do some task. For example, extract a field for an export or update a field based on some new business rule.

**Reasoning**

MapReduce seems overkill here. There's nothing to really map and there is no "reducing" either. The map is always just the key + the record. There is certainly no use for shuffle and sort since they keys are guaranteed to be unique from HBase.

For performance reasons, this should still be distributed. I guess I'm looking for a good old fashion table scan that happens to be distributed.

**Question**

What options exist to leverage the cluster but avoid the unnecessary steps of a full MapReduce job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Co-processors](https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/coprocessor_introduction) are for this exactly. From the link : "a framework for both flexible and generic extension, and of distributed computation directly within the HBase server processes".

Comment: It's not really distributed though. `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` defaults to `10737418240`. So, if the table is less than that, the entire table will get processed on a single node and not in a distributed fashion.

Comment: uh... what's your point? if you have a table with just one region you're doing it wrong.

Comment: that's like saying mapreduce isn't distributed because i might run a mapreduce job over just one block.

Comment: if there is a table with 2GB data then with a single region the coprocessor will process it on a single node. it would be a bad option to split it into 128mb regions for distributed processing. if the same 2gb data is in hdfs, because of the replication there is a better probability that the mr processing will be spread across multiple nodes for the same 128mb blocks. just my 2c. need to think more about it.

Comment: @PraveenSripati The tables in question for us are spread across dozens of servers over hundreds of regions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a map-only job - it would do exactly what you want
To get a map only job you can use the `TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob`helper method
and set no reducers `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`

Also you can push some of the processing to hbase if you specify a filter for the scan

Comment: We have tried this. However, the basic problem is that we can't seem to get a mapper only job to run as fast as a job that passes all computation to the reducers. Perhaps because we can't configure the number of mappers, whereas you can configure the number of reducers? we're not sure if it's a design of M/R jobs or if it's configurations. Thanks.

Comment: A map/reduce with HBase creates a map per region - if you partition your regions well enough you'd have as much parallelism as you like.